# How do I display a different value in a TDBComboBox than what is in the database?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have a TDBComboBox on my form. Right now it's hooked up to a database field that can only contain a `Y` or an `N`.

I'd like to pretty it up a little, and have it instead show `Yes` or `No`. How can I do this?

Comment: Take a clientdataset with two columns (key and value) and use a `TDBLookupComboBox`

Comment: If you properly made the field a boolean,, you could use [TBooleanField.DisplayValues](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.DB.TBooleanField.DisplayValues).

Comment: A "prettier" way to deal with `Y` or `N` values is to use a check-box.

Comment: @CraigYoung - The client wants a combobox, client gets a combo box :^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solutions for me was:

1. Switch the control (YesNoCombo) to TDBLookupCombobox
2. On the form in the Design view, create a TClientDataSet (called YesNoCDS) with two fields

   - DisplayValue
   - DatabaseValue
3. Right-Click on YesNoCDS and select `Create Dataset`
4. Append the data for YesNoCDS in the `FormShow` event (this seems like a kludge, but I don't see a way to do that in the Design view)
5. Create a TDataSource on the form called YesNoDS and set its `DataSet` to YesNoCDS
6. On YesNoCombo, set the `ListSource` to YesNoDS, and then set the `List Field` to DisplayValue and the `KeyField` to DatabaseValue